# How to obtain DOP on Android

Tags: android, gps

Is it possible to get the DOP (Horizontal dilution of position) for a GPS receiver that is within an Android phone? Working with GPS receivers in the past I've found the number of satellites AND the DOP greatly help in determining the accuracy and error of the signal. I'm writing an app and would like to have this additional metadata about the GPS reading if possible.  I know I can get the number of satellites by iterating through the getSatellites list, but I've yet to find anything that gives DOP or some resolution of error.

More info about DOP can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29)

Comment: can't you get the DOP from the NMEA string? [NMEA Listner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html) specifically the GGA string

Comment: Is this available from every android that has a GPS receiver?  Didn't realize this was an option.  You should make this an answer, I'd accept it!

Comment: Done. I have not used it myself but I was going to in the next few days I was looking for the raw GPS data out myself when I found this. the docs say it gets it from the GPS engine so I would asume that yes any device with GPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you get the DOP from the NMEA string?

[NMEA Listner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html)

specifically the GGA string

[GPS string reference](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gga)

EDIT i went ahead and tested the code
the output from the NMEA listener for me is

```
01-21 16:54:34.446: D/GPS(31835): Location[gps -xx.350320,xxx.764615 acc=15 et=+2d7h44m55s515ms alt=-57.70001220703125 vel=0.37530002 bear=350.0 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=44]}]
01-21 16:54:35.423: D/GPS(31835): $GPGSA,A,3,05,18,21,25,29,31,,,,,,,2.1,1.2,1.7*35
01-21 16:54:35.423: D/GPS(31835): $GPGSV,2,1,07,25,56,055,22,29,56,156,21,21,45,315,18,31,33,246,17*78
01-21 16:54:35.423: D/GPS(31835): $GPGSV,2,2,07,05,22,111,15,30,11,213,11,18,08,001,12*4E
01-21 16:54:35.446: D/GPS(31835): $GPGGA,xxxx38.000,xxx1.019145,S,xxx45.876838,E,1,06,1.2,-27.1,M,-29.7,M,,*7A
01-21 16:54:35.446: D/GPS(31835): $GPRMC,xxxx38.000,A,xx21.019145,S,xxxx45.876838,E,0.9,8.2,210113,,,A*76
```

Note that the HDOP can be found in the GPGSA & GPGGA strings
and for these strings it is 1.2

```
$GPGGA,xxxx38.000,xxx1.019145,S,11545.876838,E,1,06,**1.2**,-27.1,M,-29.7,M,,*7A
$GPGSA,A,3,05,18,21,25,29,31,,,,,,,2.1,**1.2**,1.7*35
```